# In Unity, why does my IndexOutOfRange exception disappear when trying to debug it?

Tags: unity, c#, debugging

I don't get errors when playing from Unity "Game" tab. But when I build an executable (development or not) it stucks. I get "IndexOutOfRange" exception.
Which also magically disappears (yes) when I add some debug lines:

This does not work:

```
for (int i = x1; i <= x2; i++)
for (int j = y1; j <= y2; j++)
{
    int a, b;
    a = 7 + i; // Out of range
    b = 7 + j; // Out of range

    submap[a, b] = world.WalkableMap[(int)CurrentWalkableTile.x + i, (int)CurrentWalkableTile.y + j];
}
```

This works:

```
for (int i = x1; i <= x2; i++)
for (int j = y1; j <= y2; j++)
{
    int a, b;
    a = 7 + i;
    b = 7 + j;

    if (a < 0 || a > 15) // now with this never gets out of range
        Debug.Log("A out of range: " + a);

    if (b < 0 || b > 15) // now with this never gets out of range
        Debug.Log("B out of range: " + b);

    submap[a, b] = world.WalkableMap[(int)CurrentWalkableTile.x + i, (int)CurrentWalkableTile.y + j];
}
```

I can't find any sense. The exception literally hides from me

Additional info maybe is useful:

```
x1 = (CurrentWalkableTile.x - 7) >= 0 ? -7 : -(int)CurrentWalkableTile.x;
x2 = (CurrentWalkableTile.x + 7) < world.wmap_x_size ? 7 : (world.wmap_x_size - (int)CurrentWalkableTile.x - 1);

y1 = (CurrentWalkableTile.y - 7) >= 0 ? -7 : -(int)CurrentWalkableTile.y;
y2 = (CurrentWalkableTile.y + 7) < world.wmap_y_size ? 7 : (world.wmap_y_size - (int)CurrentWalkableTile.y - 1);
```

I'd like to post more information, but I can't even debug to find the problem.

Comment: Out of bound errors are unpredictable, it may fail, it may not.  Since you use indices, what is the actual bound of a and b?

Comment: a and b are supossed to be in [0,14]; both values are 7 +/- [0, 7], depending on [x1,x2] and [y1,y2]

Comment: What container class?

Comment: submap is bool[15,15]

Comment: You've encountered the elusive [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), a bug which disappears when you add instrumentation to catch it. Do you have any information about when the exception is being thrown? ie. is it immediate when the script loads/runs for the first time, or does it happen randomly sometime later during play? If the former, that may be a clue that there could be a race condition in the initialization of the array, where under some circumstances this code gets hit before the code which initializes it. Hard to say without seeing more of the code though.

Comment: If that's c sharp, would not it be more fruitful to post on stackoverflow...  I am not sure about the answer anymore.

Comment: I achieved to get some more information. The map is initialized just before the code I posted, as full "false".  The bug throwns exactly in the first loop of i (i = -3) and the third loop of j (j = -1); in the loop I posted above. However, I suposse this is random behaviour

Comment: What are the values of world.wmap_x_size and wmap_y_size. Also what is the range of CurrenWalkableTile.x and y?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a < 0 || a > 15) // now with this never gets out of range
            Debug.Log("A out of range: " + a);

if (b < 0 || b > 15) // now with this never gets out of range
            Debug.Log("B out of range: " + b);
```

submap is bool[15,15] (according to comments)

then that should be

```
if (b < 0 || b >= 15)
```

or

```
if (b < 0 || b > 14)
```

index 15 would be already outside of bounds (size 15, indizes 0 - 14)

Since you couldn't trace your bug with the current if statement this leads to the conclusion your invalid index causing the exception is 15 and not a negative index.

---

Since part one didn't find the problem the next chance is to not check the submap[a][b] array but the world.WalkableMap[] array.

Just do the same as with a b.

```
int c = (int)CurrentWalkableTile.x + i;
int d = (int)CurrentWalkableTile.y + j;

if (c < 0 || c >= world.WalkableMap.length) Debug.Log("C out of range: " + c);
```

`if (d < 0 || d >= world.WalkableMap[0].length) Debug.Log("d out of range: " + d);`

Because you are using two arrays but so far you haven't excluded one causing the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I fixed that and still the same

Comment: Unity supports code that is only executed within the editor? Do you have such code? If index is out of bounds may the submap gets filled in editor only code and is zero zero or null in the build?

Comment: What are the values of  world.wmap_x_size  world.wmap_y_size?

Comment: I have no code which is supossed to run only in editor. Submap is never empty, i init it manually as full false. world.wmap_x_size = 96; world_wmap_y_size = 44. I tested it and it is ok

Comment: Tricky tricky. Helping you further would need more questions than suitable for comments. May we find a oppurtunity to use the chat. Next approaches would be log everything (i,j,x1,x2,....) everything and check if submap[a,b] is out of bounds or the calculations on the right side. Put the results into vars and log them too